# нужна помощь с запросом

Tags: mysql, база-данных, запрос

Задача стоит следующая посчитать количество записей от каждой категории в течении года для каждого месяца
Написал такой запрос

```
SELECT c.description, c.calendar, c.category_id, count(h.category_id) as total 
FROM help AS h
LEFT JOIN category AS c ON h.category_id = c.id
WHERE YEAR(c.calendar)=2018 
GROUP BY c.id, MONTH(c.calendar) 
ORDER BY total ASC
```

[image: Скрин]

Он почти работает, не считает почему то сколько было записей в месяце если категории разные, а когда один месяц и одна категория, то всё корректно считает, то есть надо как то сложить total для месяца и на примере скрина получить 2,2,1, но не знаю как, помогите пожалуйста

Comment: ничего не понятно. если надо количество любых категорий в месяце, то уберите категорию из group by. Если что то другое - сформулируйте как нибудь более понятно, возможно приложите исходные данные, на основе которых должны получиться ваши 2,2,1

Comment: Условие во WHERE приводит к вырождению LEFT JOIN в INNER JOIN. В зависимости от требуемой логики или замените левое связывание во внутреннее, или переместите условие по правой таблицы в секцию связывания. Судя по выражению группировки - требуется первое. Но тогда вообще теряется смысл в наличии в запросе таблицы help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поддерживаю Mike, похоже что ответ ~ такой(Сортировка по дате для наглядности)

```
SELECT c.description, c.calendar, c.category_id, count(h.category_id) as total 
FROM help AS h
LEFT JOIN category AS c ON h.category_id = c.id
WHERE YEAR(c.calendar)=2018 
GROUP BY MONTH(c.calendar) 
ORDER BY c.calendar, total ASC
```

Comment: Ваш запрос посчитал только для одной категории, но думаю подойдёт, дальше в цикле буду прогонять остальные категории и считать для них, если же у вас будут предложения как это сделать запросом не используя цикл, то заранее благодарю